# How can I specify a date picker in one of the fields in my ContractForm React component?

Tags: dapp-development, react, drizzle, datetime

I'm using the ContractForm React component available in the `drizzle-react-component` library. It's super nice and easy to setup and use, but I am dealing with a date in one of the fields (which is specified as `string` in my contract) so the ContractForm gives me the possibility to input a string and not to overload that particular input field with, say, a date picker.

Is there a way to either overload or bypass ContractForm in order to have that field as a date picker, transform the date the way I decided to handle them in Ethereum, and let ContractForm call the function on chain for me?

Thank you!